# How can I turn my old tablet PC into a Cintiq-like pen tablet?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing-tablet, hardware

I've been searching on internet but with no success... I have a old Fujitsu ST5020D Wacom Penabled tablet pc. As you know, a 1ghz Celeron + 256MB RAM wouldn't fill my needs as working on Adobe Master Suite tools.

Is there a way to work on my ST5020 as a external Pen Tablet, working as a input/output device for my computer running Illustrator & Photoshop?

As summary, is there a way to turn my ST5020 into a Cintiq like tablet?

Answer (score 5):

I have a project that does just this. (With a slightly different model tablet). [See here](http://kinggeek.co.uk/projects/item/27-diytablet)  .

The steps include:

- installing four pieces of custom software on the main Windows PC: a virtual network serial port, an alternate Wacom driver, a VNC server, and a batch file to simplify connection.
- replacing the operating system of the tablet PC with a custom .ISO by the author, based on Linux Slitaz. **NB: THIS WILL DESTROY ANY DATA ON YOUR TABLET'S HARDDISK** - so only do this if you're happy for your tablet PC to be used ***only*** as a Cintiq like tablet

Comment: Awesome! I wonder - do you know if your software would work with one of the new Windows 8 [Cintiq Companion](http://cintiqcompanion.wacom.com/CintiqCompanion/en/) tablets, enabling it to be plugged into a PC and used like a regular Cintiq? I know that a lot of people are shunning the Cintiq Companion because after a few years, once the RAM/processor are obsolete and the battery has conked out, it becomes essentially useless: this could make them more versatile and give them more re-sell value

Answer (score 1):

[Cheap Cintiq alternatives - tablet PCs with digitizers?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12994/cheap-cintiq-alternatives-tablet-pcs-with-digitizers) covers similar ground, and points out that you could use more lightweight tools (perhaps older versions of Adobe tools would work too) or use the laptop to remotely access a more powerful PC (presumably using VNC, Remote Desktop Protocol, or similar)

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with VNC solutions are that they won't transport the pen information (such as pen pressure, if the the pen is touching etc.) The method [here](http://kinggeek.co.uk/projects/item/27-diytablet) actually shares the tablet PC's inbuilt wacom digitizer over the network as a virtual serial port, thus the desktop recognizes it as a digitizer tablet. VNC is then used to push the display back to the tablet PC (which is then scaled) creating 'true' cintiq type experience. There is a video of it action [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15wrCN0ib_Q). It can be used over wi-fi as well. Software is all GPL/Free.